# python MySQLdb prepared select statement

Tags: python, select, prepared-statement, mysql-python

In python with MySQLdb I am trying to execute the following:

```
cur.execute("select COUNT(*) from adjacency where r = %d and c = %d)" % (curRow, curCol)
```

`r` and `c` are integer fields in table `adjacency` and also form a composite primary key. `curRow` and `curCol` are integer variables in my python program. 
MySQL is complaining:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%d and c = %d' at line 1")
```

Ultimately, I want to check if there already exists a row in adjacency with `r=curCow` and `c=curCol`. If so, then update a field in the table. Otherwise insert a row into the table.

1. What is wrong with my prepared statement?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "What is wrong with my prepared statement?" YOu have no prepared statement. These are not supported by the Python MySQLdb module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you just have a bracket in the wrong place.

Change...

```
cur.execute("select COUNT(*) from adjacency where r = %d and c = %d)" % (curRow, curCol)
```

...to...

```
cur.execute("select COUNT(*) from adjacency where r = %d and c = %d" % (curRow, curCol))
```

...although it's safer to use...

```
cur.execute("select COUNT(*) from adjacency where r = %s and c = %s", (curRow, curCol))
```

...which will protect you from potential SQL injection.